# Why was my flag on a seemingly link-only answer declined by a moderator?

Tags: support, declined-flags, specific-answer, link-only-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57658030/6296561) as NAA a few hours ago. Full text of the answer:

> A solution that worked for me :
>
> https://laravel.io/forum/11-15-2016-ho-to-paginate-search-results

But my flag was declined by a moderator with the default message ("a moderator has reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it").

The answer only contains a link with the typical "go here to get an answer" - no paraphrasing, no quotes, nothing that leaves any value if the link dies. It's [clearly NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/332043). Or am I missing something?

Why was my flag declined?

Comment: Definitely looks like NAA to me

Comment: The answer has now more details (which still is not enough), if you check the edit history, an NAA flag was imminent.

Comment: You need to look at the bare link here and then judge if it is NAA. In this specific case you'll get `https://laravel.io/forum/11-15-2016-ho-to-paginate-search-results` and from that we see that *ho to paginate search results* clearly is an answer ... no, wait that can't be right either ...

Comment: @yivi their flag triggerd this [LQ review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23889812) that was cut short. The question here is asked at 5:20UTC the salvaging edit was done at 5:27UTC. So we can be sure the OP, the reviewers and the mod saw a link-only answer.

Comment: Or the mod simply made a mistake in this case...

Comment: I don't think it's fair to expect reviewers to put the effort the answerer should've put into the post, into the post. They submitted a link-only answer. It's up to them to fix it.

Comment: @Cerbrus a mistake seems like the most obvious reason, but I'd still like to know if there's another reason. We've had sudden policy changes before too

Comment: @Cerbrus the post we discuss is linked here, it was called "FAQ" in currently deleted comment ([available in archive](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47142910#47142910))

Comment: Why someone plagiarized the accepted answer into that post?

Comment: @Braiam They didn’t; the included the information from the link into that post. It just so happens that there’s only one way to solve the issue the OP has.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker are you serious? It said something on the tone of "copying the accepted answer".

Comment: @braiam the accepted solution from the other site. It’s not plagiarism if you cite your source; either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should definitely not have been declined.

By all established rules, a link is not an answer. A moderator does *not* get to overwrite that rule.

It is also well established that SO answer shall be original content; a quote and a link is generally insufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Baum. Can we assume some communication is taking place to make sure we don't get many more similarly declined flags (aside from the occasional fat fingers / derp)?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes you can assume communications are under way. Watch this space

Comment: @Cerbrus As Yvette said, this has been discussed. Of course I cannot make any promises about the future actions of other moderators.

Comment: That's all I wanted to hear :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

A link-only answer *only* answers a question if the text itself answers the question:

- Use [`someFunction`].

vs

- You can find what function to use in [this link]

When it's the content *behind* that link that answers the question, It's NAA, and should probably be converted to a comment.

Assume all links in an answer are dead. Does the answer still answer the question?
If not, it's NAA.

You could look into editing some of the contents into the answer, but more often than not, there's plagiarism / content ownership issues with that.

So to answer your question: Yes, it was clearly NAA when you flagged it.

Why it was declined is a question only the moderator that declined it can answer.