# Link only answer / Software recommendations

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I flagged this recently as a link only answer (which I suggest be converted to a comment): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722674/1767412

Removing the link from that answer leaves only a copy/paste of software features. Additionally, I don't think software recommendations are acceptable if that is the only content of an answer.

Was this flag declined by mistake?

Comment: Relevant: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469)

Comment: Some mods decline flags on old posts because they were posted long before a few of these rules started applying. Your flag was correct, though.

Comment: @Larnu - [a quote and a link is generally insufficient.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388963/1767412)

Comment: Appendix to that ^: a link and a quote of text when recommending a library is never enough. Unsolicited library/tool recommendations are generally required to demonstrate usage of said library or tool as well. pointing to an off-site tutorial (or demonstration or whatever) isn't enough

Comment: 2011 let bygons be bygons, and you don't know which rules where valid at that time

Comment: @nbk Content has to abide by current rules too. That's (one reason) why we close/delete old off-topic posts when rules change.

Comment: If I were a mod I would have converted this answer (or it's previous revision, rather) to a comment, personally.

Comment: Well this just shows that the rules regarding answer (attempts) aren't that great. They are way to lenient, in my point of view, and are still kind of subjective. Similar, but younger, answers there have been deleted already and they contain more information than the linked one. Also, I assume that the length of the answer played an advantage here, although it is almost fluff. The actual answer is only *"Try a software called Access to MySQL."* with the link.

Comment: @TylerH you have my vote.

Comment: @TylerH no content has not to obide current rulesthat is why mods decline your request, what is a very good thing

Comment: @nbk mods haven't been declining my requests; not sure what you're talking about. But you're wrong, content does have to abide by current rules. And *that* is a good thing.

Comment: @TylerH I explained the cause of the declilne very explicit as did the others here

Comment: @nbk - where did you explain that? I only see "let bygons be bygons" and another comment which is barely comprehensible

Comment: @nbk It sounds like you're just guessing (like everyone else here), unless a mod has violated their agreement and shown you a screenshot of their declinations? Even other mods don't venture to guess why a particular mod declined a flag; they leave it to the declining mod to respond if they want.

Comment: Seems to me you already have your answer, in [the other meta post you found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388963). The post you flagged exactly matches the description already documented as NAA, in other guidance and the already-answered question.

Comment: As far as the suggestions above that the post should be converted to a comment, I disagree with that. If the post were fresh, that would be one thing. But comments are ephemeral; there's no benefit in converting a ten-year-old post to a comment now. The post should just be deleted, especially given that it doesn't even include any details on _how_ to use the recommended software.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - thanks, I agree it's a dupe.  I still wanted to get fresh eyes on it since it might have been a mistake during review of the flag.

Comment: @Zoe - it's not a flag reason, though. The NAA guidance makes a distinction between link-only answers and "links to an answer". This is the former case, it contains everything needed (a name of the tool and a quoted description). The flag was declined correctly, we had a discussion about this a little while ago. **However**: the post is of low quality. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407225/11407695

Comment: @billynoah it is implizit first comes the date it is from 201, then comes to let old post stay as they are, last i point out that we don't kn ow the rules from that time, and what was allowed and what not, the rest you can think for yourself